# Inserting rows to reflect missing data

Tags: r, merge, data-wrangling

I am working on a function that outputs a data frame that currently omits trials where there is missing data. However, I would like the full trial count to be added back into the file and the other data columns be blank for these instances (reflecting the missing data).

Example Data Frames:

```
Df1withTrialCount <- data.frame(Participant = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A' ), 
Trial = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10),
NotRelevantVariable = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,4,3,2,1,1,2,3,4,5))

Df2NeedsTrialsAddedIn <- data.frame(Participant = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'), 
Trial = c(1,3,5,6,10),
EyeGaze = c(.4, .2., .2, .1, .1))
```

So I would end up with something that had one row each for Trials 1-10 but blanks in Eye Gaze when there was not data (e.g., Trial 2 would have a blank for EyeGaze but Trial 3 would have .2).

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Take care and thank you for your time,
Caroline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `base::merge`:

```
merge(unique(Df1withTrialCount[, c("Participant", "Trial")]),
      Df2NeedsTrialsAddedIn,
      all.x = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `complete`

```
library(tidyr)
complete(Df2NeedsTrialsAddedIn, Participant, 
        Trial = seq_len(max(Df1withTrialCount$Trial)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
#   Participant Trial EyeGaze
#   <chr>       <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 A               1     0.4
# 2 A               2    NA  
# 3 A               3     0.2
# 4 A               4    NA  
# 5 A               5     0.2
# 6 A               6     0.1
# 7 A               7    NA  
# 8 A               8    NA  
# 9 A               9    NA  
#10 A              10     0.1
```

---

If we need both `min` and `max from first dataset

```
complete(Df2NeedsTrialsAddedIn, Participant, 
        Trial = seq(min(Df1withTrialCount$Trial), max(Df1withTrialCount$Trial), by = 1))
```

Comment: This is great. Since I am doing this within a function that will have varying trial numbers is there a way to adapt the Trial count to pull the highest numbered trial from the other dataset (df1 in the example)?

Comment: @Caroline. Do you have the `min` as always 1?  Or should that also be created from the first data.  I updated based on the `max` of the first data Trial

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

Df1withTrialCount %>% 
  left_join(Df2NeedsTrialsAddedIn, by=c('Participant', 'Trial')) %>% 
  distinct(Trial, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Comment: While this may provide the answer, code without explanation does not help the OP or others that will come to SO for answers. Please read about what to do when someone [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) your question.